# French words appearing weird on Google Chrome

Tags: character-encoding

I'm translating my web application to French and noticed on Google Chrome when I view my words that it doesn't display the words correctly but instead adds weird characters. Is there a a meta language or some src tag I can insert into my HTML to fix this problem?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/g67pURA.png]

Comment: encoding encoding encoding...

Comment: Can you explain further in-depth? I've made my collation `utf8_unicode_ci` in my phpymyadmin mySQL database.

Comment: In fact, you need to give us more informations (like you did a bit in your comment) so we can help you :)

Comment: You're right, thank you for leading me to the right direction though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is your encoding?

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
```

Comment: This is a quite sparse _answer_. Don't you think it had better been a comment?

Comment: Thank you very much! I was checking my header section and did not have UTF-8 encoding. This works now.